# Change the place where the a tag close

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with html content with links that close on the wrong place and I need to place it in the right place. Let me explain the pattern:

All the links are followed by the a `<sup>` tag or by an `*`. I need the `a` tag to close after `*` or the `</sub>`. Example:

```
<a href="#" class="ddb1"><sup id="v3534" class="ddb17">34</sup> No harás impura la tierra en que habitáis, porque yo habito en medio de ella, pues yo, Yahvé, tengo mi morada entre los israelitas.»</a>
```

Should be like this:

```
<a href="#" class="ddb1"><sup id="v3534" class="ddb17">34</sup></a> No harás impura la tierra en que habitáis, porque yo habito en medio de ella, pues yo, Yahvé, tengo mi morada entre los israelitas.»
```

And

```
La herencia de la mujer casada<a href="notas04nm.xhtml#nnm170ref" class="ddb1">*.</a>
```

Should be:

```
La herencia de la mujer casada<a href="notas04nm.xhtml#nnm170ref" class="ddb1">*</a>.
```

The issue is that in the string may have `*` and `sup` tags that are no inside links, so, I can't simply delete the `</a>` and replace the `*` for `*</a>` and the `</sup>` for `</sup></a>`. So, I think the right way to do it is with Regex, but I am really bad with this.

An example string that represent very nicely the *real string* is this:

```
<sup id="v3530" class="ddb17">30</sup> «En cualquier caso de homicidio, se matará al homicida según la declaración de los testigos; pero un solo testigo no bastará para condenar a muerte a un hombre*. <sup id="v3531" class="ddb17">31</sup> No aceptaréis rescate por la vida de un homicida reo de muerte, pues debe morir. <sup id="v3532" class="ddb17">32</sup> Tampoco aceptaréis rescate por el que se ha refugiado en la ciudad de asilo y quiere volver a habitar en su tierra antes que muera el Sumo Sacerdote. <a href="#" class="ddb1"><sup id="v3533" class="ddb17">33</sup> No profanaréis la tierra en que estáis, porque aquella sangre profana la tierra, y la tierra no queda expiada de la sangre derramada más que con la sangre del que la derramó. </a><a href="#" class="ddb1"><sup id="v3534" class="ddb17">34</sup> No harás impura la tierra en que habitáis, porque yo habito en medio de ella, pues yo, Yahvé, tengo mi morada entre los israelitas.»</a> La herencia de la mujer casada<a href="notas04nm.xhtml#nnm170ref" class="ddb1">*.</a>
```

**Note:**

The string has latin characters like `áéíóúñ`.

**EDIT:**

I have this piece of code that works for the 2 first examples but no for the 3rd (the one that says is an *example of the real string*):

```
function sMove($string){
    preg_match('/<a.*?\>(.*?)<\/a>/si', $string, $atags);
    if ( isset( $atags[0] )) {
        if (preg_match('/<sup.*?\>(.*?)<\/sup>/si', $atags[0], $matches)) {
            $sup = $matches[0];
            $text = str_replace($sup, '', $atags[1]);
            $string = str_replace($text, '', $string) . $text;       
        }
        if (preg_match('/\*./', $atags[0], $matches)) {
            $string = str_replace($matches[0], '*', $string) . '.';
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Any way you can shorten, take out the garbage text in that 1k wide string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* (not saying you should) use the following expression:

```
<a[^>]*>(?:\*|<sup[^>]*>.*?</sup>)\K(.*?)</a>
```

This needs to be replaced with

```
</a>$1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BL4eyC/2) (and mind the modifiers!).

---

Broken down, this reads:

```
<a[^>]*>                   # likely an opening anchor tag
(?:\*|<sup[^>]*>.*?</sup>) # * or <sup...>...</sup>
\K                         # forget what's been matched thus far
                           # (but remember the position)
(.*?)                      # match anything lazily...
</a>                       # ... up to </a>
```

However, consider using a parser and `DOM` functions instead as this is a bit hacky and error-prone to nested tags and attributes (i.e. `data-tags`).